Xcode Cloud exit code 70
Ever since I upgrade to Xcode 16 RC, my Xcode Cloud archives have been failing. I was hoping that once the official Xcode 16 release came out the issue would be resolved, but even after Xcode 16.1 the issue still persists. The ad-hoc and app-store archives appear to be working but there is a development archive that keeps failing:

Any idea why this is happening? Is it something to do with provisioning or signing? I'm currently letting Xcode manage both signing and provisioning.
